# ENTER/ RETURN key in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have pycharm 2019.3.4 and I am new to python. Why is it that when I click the enter/return key it runs the line of code? Is there a way I can disable this so that I can enter all my code and then run them directly?
For example, I want to type several lines of code before running, I don't like pycharm executing each line as I press ENTER

Comment: Are you in a terminal/console or editing a file?

Comment: I am in python console

Comment: That's how a python console works? It's nothing to do with PyCharm. If you want to write several lines of code before running you should create a script (.py file)